# regex to replace multiple subsequent line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is what I want to do.

1. Replace more than 3 line breaks with 3 line breaks.
2. Replace 2 line breaks with 1 line break.
3. Ignore single line breaks.

So that something like this:

```
Dear Bob



I would love to not have so many line breaks here.

This is a new paragraph.




Thanks

Jim
```

Ends up more like this:

```
Dear Bob

I would love to not have so many line breaks here.
This is a new paragraph.

Thanks
Jim
```

Based on another question, this is the closest I've come, but it's not quite right:

```
innerHTML.replace(/\n\n\s*\n\n/g, '\n');
```

Comment: Not quite right how? Remember "more than three" means `\n\n\n+`.

Comment: It's hard to explain because the real data is private.  I will try to obfuscate it and add the exact results to my question as soon as I can.

Comment: Will there be `\n` only line breaks? No `\r\n`s?

Comment: I'm not sure, that may be part of the problem.

Comment: If you can create some dummy text in a similar structure that would be sufficient.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zo25rwb1/).

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I want!  Can you please post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex with an alternation group, one alternative will match 4+ linebreaks, and the other just 2 (that is not preceded nor followed with a line break).

The regex will be:

```
((?:\r?\n){4,})|(^|[^\n])(?:\r?\n){2}(?!\r?\n)
```

*Explanation*:

- `((?:\r?\n){4,})` - Alternative 1 matching 4+ sequences of an optional `\r` followed with a compulsory `\n`
- `|` - or...
- `(^|[^\n])(?:\r?\n){2}(?!\r?\n)` - Alternative 2 matching exactly 2 sequences of an optional `\r` followed with a compulsory `\n` that are not preceded (`(^|[^\n])` matches either the start of string or a character other than `\n`) nor followed with a linebreak (the negative lookahead `(?!\r?\n)` makes sure of that).

In the replacement, there is a callback checking which alternative matched and replaces accodingly.

The JS code demo is below:

```js
var re = /((?:\r?\n){4,})|(^|[^\n])(?:\r?\n){2}(?!\r?\n)/g; 
var str = `Dear Bob



I would love to not have so many line breaks here.

This is a new paragraph.




Thanks

Jim`;
var result = str.replace(re, function (m, g1, g2) {
 return g1 ? "\n\n" : g2 + "\n";
});
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + result + "</pre>";
```

Comment: You can adjust the linebreaks, e.g. add `\r`.

Comment: If this were Reddit I would tag you as `Regex God`

Comment: I am not a regex god. :)